# How to listen for firebase events in android background service?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Tried to listen for firebase events in background Service. Please find code snippet below,

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {           
       Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);        
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {        
     }
   };
   mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);

   return START_STICKY;
 }
```

onDataChange() method is getting untill my Activity is alive, once Activity is exited,  the method is not getting called.

Anyone please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by using a service?  Why wouldn't you just set up the listener directly in the activity that uses the data?

Comment: I want to sync data in background without opening activity

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, be sure that `android:stopWithTask` is not set to `true`. Either set it to `false`, or leave it out altogether since it defaults to `false`. That way, the Service will be uncorrelated to Activity's lifecycle. Your manifest should look something like this:

```xml
 <service
    android:name=".your_package_here.your_service_class_here"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```